# How to avoid Generics in this case?

Tags: java, generics

```
class Attribute<T>{
   private T attr;
   public Attribute(T attr){
      this.attr = attr;
   } 
}

Class Matrix<T>{
   private String name;
   List<Attribute<T>> list;

   public Matrix(String name, T t){
     this.name = name;
     list = new ArrayList<>();
     list.add(new Attribute<T>(t)); 
  }
}

 interface Extractor<T> {
    public List<Matrix<T>> extract();
}

InfoExtractor implements Extractor<String>{

    public List<Matrix<String>> extract(){ 
       List<Matrix<String>> matrixList = new ArrayList<>();

        // The problem is here!!!!
        matrixList.add(new Matrix<String>("abc")); 
    }
 }

 Document<T>{
      Map<String, List<Matrix<T>>> matrixMap;

        public void process(){
        ...
         Extractor<T> extractor = (Extractor<T>) new StringExtractor(sent);
        List<Matrix<T>> matrix = extractor.extract(...);
   }
```

My question is, is there a way to avoid defining Matrix as a generic type ? The reason I want to avoid is that the "`List<Attribute<T>>` " is used in multiple other classes, either as private member variables, or method return types. Due to Attribute, it seems I have to define some other related classes as generic types too, which causes my problem.

In this case, is there a way to not define Matrix as generic, but keep the  "list" variable as a generic type?

Comment: Then you'd have to decide which generic type for the list variable. Some type has to be assigned

Comment: So when you write `Matrix m = new Matrix()`, what do you expect the `list`'s type to be? `List<Attribute>`?

Comment: Show how you're using this generified code. Essentially there's nothing wrong with the generics there (Attribute is pretty much a glorified wrapper, not needed), you essentially have `Matrix<T>` which is a `List<T>` with a name.

Comment: Please see my addition.

Comment: It would be helpful to have some information on the signatures of methods inside Matrix.

Comment: @Rogue, Attribute<T> has a variable of type T and that's the point. It is not a wrapper.

Comment: But it _is_ a wrapper for that `T` you pass to the constructor, it literally just holds a single `T` value. I get it may be a watered down example, but atm it'd help to see your use-case.

Comment: I think your actual problem is with the signature of `Extractor.extract()`. Its `T` type variable is not constrained to anything, which is usually nonsensical. If `Extractor` were `Extractor<T>` then `InfoExtractor` could implement `Extractor<String>` and I think that would solve your problem.

Comment: Why do you need type of Attribute? I think you should redesign a bit your app. If you remove generic type from Attribute it will helps you remove types  from other related code.

Comment: @eg04lt3r  because I have to deal with different type of Attribute's variable attr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem lies not in the generic implementation, but in its usage:

```
class InfoExtractor implements Extractor{

    // The problem is actually here
    public <T> List<Matrix<T>> extract(){ 
       List<Matrix<T>> matrixList = new ArrayList<>(); //and here

        // "The problem is here!!!!"
        matrixList.add(new Matrix<String>("abc")); 
    }
}
```

The `<T>` indicates that you are binding a new generic type relative to the method invocation. In short, a new `T` type just for this method's execution. You also make a `List<Matrix<T>>` but then attempt to add a new `Matrix<String>` back. If you know the list is going to be of the type `Matrix<String>`, then you can specify that in `InfoExtractor`:

```
//If you cannot generify the interface for some reason
interface Extractor {
    public List<? extends Matrix<?>> extract(); //explained at bottom
}

//IDEALLY, then implement Extractor<String> instead
interface Extractor<T> {
    public List<Matrix<T>> extract();
}

class InfoExtractor implements Extractor { //or Extractor<String>

    public List<Matrix<String>> extract() {
        List<Matrix<String>> matrixList = new ArrayList<>();
        matrixList.add(new Matrix<>("abc"));
        return matrixList;
    }
}
```

Of course, you can see the method signature for `Extractor` changed. Due to using a nested generic on the return type, things will get a bit messy for type matching at compile-time. The `<?>` for the Matrix is fairly self-explanatory, we're returning multiple and possibly unknown types inside of the Matrix.

By specifying `? extends Matrix` on `Extractor`, we're specifying the proper variance. Concrete generics are *invariant*, thus a `List<Toyota>` isn't a `List<Car>`, even if `Toyota` is a subclass of `Car`. If we want the `Matrix` to be *covariant*, then we need the bounding on Matrix as well unfortunately. This means in effect, ignoring Liskov's substitution principal, we'd essentially be referencing the concrete subclasses for the extractors (`InfoExtractor ex` vs `Extractor ex`), especially from a usability standpoint (as the concrete classes can return proper type safety whereas the interface cannot).

This of course, is handled much more sanely/cleanly when you specify the `<T>` for the matrices in the list as a class-level generic type.

Comment: If you look at the Document, List<Matrix<T>> matrix = extractor.extract(...); I have to do a cast from List<Matrix<String>> to List<Matrix<T>>, which is what i was trying to avoid.  Please see the Document.process method.

Comment: You still snipped out too much code. You reference an `extractor` variable which we aren't provided, and you're essentially generifying Document when it doesn't necessarily need it. What are you attempting to accomplish through doing this, and what kind of information is available to you? Keep in mind, if the types don't match, you don't have a `List<T>` you have a `List<?>`

Comment: I defined Document<T> due to the variable " Map<String, List<Matrix<T>>> matrixMap;" You can see the List<Matrix<T>>. I actually don't store different types into a list at the same time. For the same list object, the List stores the same type of Matrix<T>.

Comment: Right, but what are you mapping? And what's `extractor` (an InfoExtractor instance?)?. Lastly, I think you're looking for the wildcard, not a class-level generic. So basically `List<Matrix<?>>` and `Document`

Comment: Is the wildcard way Matrix<?> good practice? The concern I am having is that, my list object should always store the same type of object, for the same list.

Comment: Well, once you reference the list as `List<? extends Matrix<?>>`, you won't be able to add new items to it (for specifically that reason). So you'd create your concrete `List<Matrix<?>>`, and then add them to the map to prevent adding random values. The Matrix is only wildcarded because you have multiple matrix types in your multiple collections (and if you don't, you didn't need generics anyhow). PECS applies here (e.g. a `List<? super Matrix<?>>` would accept new values).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you would like to do.

If you intend to use Matrix to hold a single type of attribute, that is T then the best approach seems to be the one you posted as you get to have compile time type checking.

If you remove the generic type T from Matrix then you cannot know the type of each attribute. You can completely remove T from Matrix declaration and use the wildcard for the Attribute variable. While this would allow you to store attributes of different T types in the same Matrix object, it will remove the compile type checking. In other words, the classes using the Matrix would have to know what class to expect and perhaps cast each attribute to the class expected.

```
Class Matrix{
   private String name;
   List<Attribute<?>> list;

   public Matrix(String name, T t){
     this.name = name;
     list = new ArrayList<>();
     list.add(new Attribute<>(t)); 
  }
}
```

Adding a Class variable and saving the Class object inside the attribute, could help you retain some information in runtime to identify the class of the objects inside the attribute.

```
class Attribute<T>{
   private T attr;
   private final Class<T> clazz;

   public Attribute(T attr, Class<T> clazz){
      this.attr = attr;
      this.clazz=clazz;
   } 

    public Attribute(T attr){
      this.attr = attr;
      Objects.requireNonNull(attr);
      this.clazz= (Class<T>) attr.getClass();
   } 
}
```

Using this approach the original constructor can be used only for non null values, otherwise the class object should be provided by the programmer.

Comment: This could be improved by specifying that clazz has to be a `Class<T>` instead of a `Class<?>`

Comment: The post was updated as indicated in the comment. The difference is not big, since T will be lost in runtime, so T could not be somehow used. However it is easier to read the code.